# why is std::views::istream not exhausted with take_while

Tags: c++, istream, std-ranges, c++23

I was trying to get all words (sequence of non whitespace characters) out of a file. In trying to do so, I accidently created an infinite loop, because at the end of the file, no more word is extracted, but the stream is not exhausted yet. **Note** I realized, that just using `std::views::istream<std::string>(file_stream)` would have solved my problems, but I am interested, in the why.

My code:
compiler used: Clang 18.1.0
with flags: -std=c++23 -stdlib=libc++

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

constexpr auto is_white_space = [](char ch) constexpr {
    return std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch));
};

struct word_extractor {
    std::string word;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &s, word_extractor &we) {
        std::string buff = std::ranges::subrange(std::istreambuf_iterator{s},
                                                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}) 
                         | std::views::drop_while(is_white_space)
                         | std::views::take_while([](auto x) { 
                               return !is_white_space(x); 
                           })
                         | std::ranges::to<std::string>();

        //if (s.peek() == EOF) s.get(); // uncommenting this code makes it work
        we.word = buff;
        return s;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::istringstream file_stream("lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ");

    auto parsed_words = std::views::istream<word_extractor>(file_stream)
                      | std::views::transform([](const word_extractor &word_extractor)
                        {
                            return word_extractor.word;
                        })
                      | std::ranges::to<std::vector<std::string>>();

    for (auto w : parsed_words) {
        std::cout << std::format("{{{}}}\n", w);
    }
}
```

output with `if (s.peek() == EOF) s.get()`:

```
{Lorem}
{ipsum}
{dolor}
{sit}
{amet}
```

no output without `if (s.peek() == EOF) s.get()`, due to infinite loop.

Without the commented line of manually consuming `EOF`, the code gets stuck in an infinite loop, as `std::views::istream<word_extractor>(file_stream)` tries to call `operator>>` forever. Why is the stream not exhausted, as I first consume all white space characters and then all non white space ones?

**Question:** Is there a way to make this kind of extraction work with c++ ranges or is the (ugly) manual check for `EOF` needed?

Comment: Please try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide input file and expected result. Also compiler and its version.

Comment: Note also that defining function in place where friendship is declared can lead to strange errors. Move definition of this function outside of class/struct.

Comment: @MarekR That's a very typical way of implementing an extraction operator, I'm not sure what strange errors you mean but that's definitely unrelated to the issue here.

Comment: _"uncommenting this code makes it work"_ - So, you expect everything but the last word to be extracted?

Comment: no, when the line is uncommented, all the words get extracted,  otherwise the code will try to extract words even after the last word is extracted, because `std::views::istream` continues to call `operator>>` and the view never finished

Comment: I see, the extraction requires a whitespace after the last word. I edited it to fix that.

Comment: It's interesting that just using `subrange(...) | to<std::string>` _directly_ on the stream extracts the whole thing as one `std::string` fine, so it seems that the thing in `main` messes it up somehow - or it's the `drop_while`/`take_while` that messes it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [pointed out by T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77956722/), streambuf iterators will not change the state of the stream. To still use a range pipeline, another `views::istream<char>` can be used instead of `ranges::subrange()`:

```
struct word_extractor {
    std::string word;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &s, word_extractor &we) {
        s >> std::noskipws;                                // don't skip ws
        std::string buff = std::views::istream<char>(s) |  // read single char from stream
                           std::views::drop_while(is_white_space) |
                           std::views::take_while([](auto x) { return !is_white_space(x); }) |
                           std::ranges::to<std::string>();
        we.word = buff;
        return s;
    }
};
```

Note however, the white-spaces are still needed for separation, thus `s >> std::noskipws` is done to prevent white-spaces from being skipped, by the `operator>>` applied to `char`.

Answer (score 3):

streambuf iterators iterate over the streambuf (even if constructed from the stream as a convenience), they won't touch the state of the stream. Without the commented-out code, nothing in `operator>>` is setting `failbit` to inform `istream_view` that an extraction failed and iteration should stop.